# Eclipse can manage local history for a non svn project?

Tags: eclipse, local, history

I ask myself if is there a way with Eclipse (I use PDT) to manage a local history for a non SVN project. I saw the local history work only on an svnsvn project.
Maybe there is an option or a plugin?

Thanks

Comment: you ask not yourself but us. Eclipse can integrate different version control systems, so yes it can do it for non-svn projects.

Comment: Thanks for response, i must be more specific in my question, when i say non svn project i mean a project without version control system. A simple project.

Comment: Then no, you can't.

Comment: Thanks again for your responsiveness.

Comment: you can create local git repo, and schedule script to commit all code every minute, or manually. So you will have history in git repo and can rollback to old version any time. This scenario doesn't required remote git server, all you need is git client installed.